# Python tkinter single label with bold and normal text

Tags: fonts, tkinter, label, bold

My question is if there is a way to put in a single ttk.label() a text that show the full text with only some words in the **bold font** like this.
I am doing this right now applying styles to many ttk.labels(), but this method imply that I must position every label next to the other, and that the program is multilingual, some strings don't fit correctly with the window.
If there is a way to do this, it will be a great advantage to my work.
Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

No, you cannot change the attributes of only some of the characters in a `Label` widget. If you need to style individual character you need to use a small `Text` widget.

For example:

```
text = tk.Text(root, height=1, font="Helvetica 12")
text.tag_configure("bold", font="Helvetica 12 bold")

text.insert("end", "Hello, ") 
text.insert("end", "world", "bold") 
text.configure(state="disabled")
```

Comment: That's not the method I expected but it works like I want.
Thanks!