# How to print every item in a tuple of tuples in different order

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have written code to show data from a sql query in tkinter. From a search function I want to print out the first item in the tuple on one line, then the rest of the results on another. I know that every tuple in the tuple has four data items (date, name , start time, end time), but I cant figure out how to get it to work properly.

```
def searched():
    Main_Screen.configure(state = 'normal')
    Main_Screen.delete('1.0', END)
    searched_for = search.get()
    timeslot = cursor.execute('''SELECT * FROM dates WHERE Name = (?)''',(searched_for,))
    list1 = list(cursor.fetchall())
    print(list1)
    cursor.execute('''SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dates WHERE Name = (?) ''',(searched_for,))
    result = cursor.fetchone()[0]
    print(result)
    n = 1
    m = 1
    for i in range(0, result - 1):
        my_variable = list1[m-1][n-1]
        Main_Screen.insert(tkinter.END,my_variable)
        Main_Screen.insert(tkinter.END, "\n")
        for i in range(0,3):
            my_var2 = list1[m-1][2-1]
            Main_Screen.insert(tkinter.END,my_var2)

            my_var3 = list1[m-1][3-1]
            Main_Screen.insert(tkinter.END,my_var3)

            my_var4 = list1[m-1][4-1]
            Main_Screen.insert(tkinter.END,my_var3)

            Main_Screen.insert(tkinter.END, "\n")
            m = m + 1
```

For example I search for everything with the name 'test'. The list I receive is:

```
[('2017-07-14', 'test', '11:00:00', '13:00:00'), ('2017-07-21', 'test', '11:00:00', '13:00:00'), ('2017-07-28', 'test', '11:00:00', '13:00:00'), ('2017-08-04', 'test', '11:00:00', '13:00:00'), ('2017-08-11', 'test', '11:00:00', '13:00:00'), ('2017-03-10', 'test', '12:00:00', '14:00:00')]

6(how many are in the main tuple)
```

but when it prints to the gui:

```
2017-07-14
test11:00:0011:00:00
test11:00:0011:00:00
test11:00:0011:00:00
2017-08-04
test11:00:0011:00:00
test11:00:0011:00:00
test12:00:0012:00:00
```

What I want:

```
Date of timeslot
Name of Timeslot
Start Time
End Time
```

Also for some reason I get this error:

```
  File "C:\Users\dansi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\gui test 3.py", line 124, in searched
my_variable = list1[m-1][n-1]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

EDIT=

```
def searched():
    Main_Screen.configure(state = 'normal')
    Main_Screen.delete('1.0', END)
    searched_for = search.get()
    timeslot = cursor.execute('''SELECT * FROM dates WHERE Name = (?)''',(searched_for,))
    list1 = list(cursor.fetchall())
    print(list1)
    cursor.execute('''SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dates WHERE Name = (?) ''',(searched_for,))
    result = cursor.fetchone()[0]
    print(result)
    for tuple_vars in list1:
        for var0, var1, var2 ,var3 in tuple_vars:
            header = '{}\n'.format(var0)
            Main_Screen.insert(tkinter.END, header)  # ADD SOME FORMATTING
            output = '{}\n{}\n{}\n{}\n'.format(var1, var2, var3)
            Main_Screen.insert(tkinter.END, output)

for i in range(0, result - 1):
    Main_Screen.insert(tkinter.END, "\n")
```

and get new error:

```
  File "C:\Users\dansi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\gui test 3.py", line 122, in searched
for var0, var1, var2 ,var3 in tuple_vars:
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 4)
```

Comment: You forgot to add more `"\n"`s to your `Main_Screen.insert`s I suppose.

Comment: So the example you show is what `list1` contains?

Comment: that separates every line but for some reason get an error. Ill update the question to show it @AshishNitinPatil

Comment: @Roelant Yes, list1 contains whats in the list when I search the database for  'test'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Never used tkinter, but thinking that you could format the entire string before sending it to tkinter:

```
for tuple_vars in list1:
    output = '{}\n{}\n{}\n{}\n'.format(*tuple_vars)
    Main_Screen.insert(tkinter.END, output)
```

Should work if its true that

```
list1 = [('2017-07-14', 'test', '11:00:00', '13:00:00'), 
         ('2017-07-21', 'test', '11:00:00', '13:00:00')]
```

To do it in two steps

```
for var1, var2, var3, var4 in list1:
    header = '{}\n'.format(var1)
    Main_Screen.insert(tkinter.END, header)  # ADD SOME FORMATTING
    output = '{}\n{}\n{}\n'.format(var2, var3, var4)
    Main_Screen.insert(tkinter.END, output)
```

Comment: Thanks, it works :) I know this might be hard to do, but I wanted to have the date bigger than the rest of the others, like a heading. Do you know how to select it first with your method, or not.

Comment: haha, no clue how you do bold in tkinter (maybe see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40237671/python-tkinter-single-label-with-bold-and-normal-text ), but splitting should be easy. See my edit.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Roelant . I am a bit confused in how to combine your two aswers. The first one worked for each one in the list, and your second one, does one tuple. How would I combine them do each one in the main tuple? update the question to show newer code and new error.

Comment: Changed my code (made a small mistake). In your edit code, you should not have the two loops but only the last one from my post.